# I want to embed video on my page by fetching the trailer link from JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json, iframe, angularjs-ng-repeat

JSON data:

```
{
    "title": "House of Cards",
    "poster": "img/hoc1.jpg",
    "imdbID": "tt1856010",
    "trailer": "NTzycsqxYJ0"
},
{
    "title": "Master of None",
    "poster": "img/mon1",
    "imdbID": "tt4635276",
    "trailer": "6bFvb3WKISk"
}
```

and I have to fetch "trailer": "6bFvb3WKISk" link from JSON into my iframe link

```
<iframe src={`https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/{{}}?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0`}
        frameBorder="0"
        allowFullScreen
        title={{}} />
```

by using `ng-repeat` directive

Please help me out

Comment: Do you hav a controller? Where does your JSON data come from?

Comment: yes i do have controllers

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/u6udn92lycaope6/TV%20shows.json

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-src.

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
    <iframe ng-src="setLink(d.trailer)" />
</div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.setLink = function(arg){
    return 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/'+arg+'?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0';
}
```

Hope it Helps !